# Get Facebook Friendlist (only read)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an app which is super important to get the user's friends.

I just need to get a **list of friends** (Avatar and name) **I do not require any more information or want to do anything with that data**, you simply get a list of friends.

With the new change in Facebook it is impossible?

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

See point 3.) of

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

> /me/friends returns the user's friends who are also using your app
>   In v2.0, the friends API endpoint returns the list of a person's friends who are also using your app. In v1.0, the response included all of a person's friends.
>
> There are two key use cases where apps need access to non-app friends: tagging and inviting. In v2.0, we've added the Taggable Friends API and the Invitable Friends API to support these flows.